# Create Custom Windows Bootable Utility Disk

Tags: windows, boot, utilities

I'm looking into the possibility of creating a windows (7?) boot image, much like the Windows install disk, but ONLY for running a slimmed-down windows shell.  I don't want to make an install disk.  I want windows to simply boot up, with dome some utility icons on the desktop for users to launch.  Any ideas on the best approach to this task?  Thanks.

Comment: Look into [Windows PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Luke for the answer.  For others also looking, you can find more details here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx